# System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input (Line: 26, Column: 1) - Salesforce

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to connect two salesforce org and through REST API and I am fetching data from Org B to Org A.

In Org A, I have written below code. But while running debug, **I am getting the error - System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input (Line: 26, Column: 1)**

Org A code

```
public class GetAccountUsingRESTAPI {
    private final String clientId = 'XXXXXX';
    private final String clientSecret = 'XXXXXX';
    private final String username = 'XXXX';
    private final String password = 'XXXX';
    public class deserializeResponse
    {
        public String id;
       public String access_token;
    }
    public String ReturnAccessToken (GetAccountUsingRESTAPI acount)
    {
        String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&amp;client_id='+clientId+'&amp;client_secret='+clientSecret+'&amp;username='+username+'&amp;password='+password;

                    //  ‘grant_type=password&client_id=’+clientId+’&client_secret=’ +clientSecret+’&username=’+username+’&password=’+password;

        system.debug('clientId' + clientId);
         system.debug('clientId' + clientSecret);
         system.debug('clientId' + username);
         system.debug('clientId' + password);


        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://praveelightningwebcomponent-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

       system.debug('res.getbody()'+ res.getbody());

        deserializeResponse response = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
        system.debug('@@@@access_token@@'+response );
        return response.access_token;


    }

    public static list<account> callGetAccount()
    {
        GetAccountUsingRESTAPI acount1 = new GetAccountUsingRESTAPI();
        String accessToken;

        accessToken = acount1.ReturnAccessToken (acount1);
        list<account> ListAccount=new List<account>();
        if(accessToken != null){
            String endPoint = 'https://praveelightningwebcomponent-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/services/apexrest/v1/getAccounts/*';
            Http h2 = new Http();
            HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
            req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
            req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
            req1.setMethod('GET');
            req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
            HttpResponse res1 = h2.send(req1);
            String trimmedResponse = res1.getBody().unescapeCsv().remove('\\');
            system.debug('@@@RESPONSE@@'+trimmedResponse);
            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res1.getBody());
            set<account> accList=new set<account>();

            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) ){
                    Account acc;
                    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'Id')) {
                        parser.nextToken();
                        String sId= parser.getText();
                        acc=new Account();
                        acc.Id=sId;
                        system.debug('Id@@@' + sId);
                        parser.nextToken();
                        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
                            (parser.getText() == 'Name')) {
                                parser.nextToken();
                                string sName= parser.getText();
                                acc.Name=sName;
                                system.debug('Name@@@' + sName );
                            }
                    }
                    accList.add(acc);
                }
                accList.remove(null);
            }
            ListAccount.AddAll(accList);
            system.debug('AccountList@@@@'  + Json.serialize(ListAccount));
        }
        return ListAccount;
    }

}
```

In Org B, I have written below code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/getAccounts/*')
global with sharing class FetchAccount {
    @HttpGet
    global static list<account> fetchAccount(){
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = Restcontext.response;
        List<account> listAccount =[Select Id , Name from Account LIMIT 10 ];
        return listAccount ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request body is malformed JSON.  You need {} around the entire thing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change only this
String reqbody = 'grant_type=password' + '&client_id='+clientId +
'&client_secret='+clientSecret + '&username='+username + '&password='+password;

Comment: How are you proposing that a missing Remote Site Setting would produce a `JSONException` as described in this question?